# ¿ Cómo deslizar una imagen con texto bajo?

Tags: java, android

Quiero tener 1 imagen, 1 `TextView` y unos cuantos iconos en mi pantalla. Lo que pasa que no me cabe todo en una y habrá que deslizar la pantalla como cuando hay una `ListView`, pero en este caso no la hay.

Primero seria imagen. Debajo el texto y debajo los iconos. Lo que realmente quiero es que el usuario deslice el dedo y la foto que esté arriba se esconda a la vez que la pantalla va subiendo. No sé si logro explicarme.

No sé como se llama eso que quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tu necesitas es un ScrollView, es un contenedor que se adapta al tamaño del contenido dentro del mismo

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/imagen"/>
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/texto"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Puedes dejar la propiedad `android:layout_height` con el valor `"wrap_content"`, y este ScrollView crecera todo lo necesario sin sobrepasar el tamaño de la pantalla (o el contenedor padre), o le puedes poner un tamaño definido como `"300dp"`. Si el contenido es mas alto que la altura del contenedor entonces podrás deslizar el contenido arriba y abajo (en este caso).

Comment: Exacto, eso quería. Por cierto, si pongo la imagen arriba y el usuario baja para leer texto, como hago como en whatsapp cuando entras a un perfil? El bajar y que la foto se ponga en pequeño en una esquina? Para que el usuario aunque baje mucho siempre esté viéndola

Comment: Especificamente lo que pides no estoy seguro de como hacerlo, pero haria algo como esto:

Comment: La imagen no seria parte del contenido del ScrollView, estaria sobre el ScrollView con el tamaño fijo, el texto tendria un margin-top del tamaño de la imagen, y pondria un listener para saber la cantidad de scroll que se esta haciendo, y en base a esa cantidad, reducir la imagen hasta un tamaño especifico.

Comment: Me conformo, gracias Sander, +1